# jQuery navigates to controller method?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, yii2

I've a project in Yii2. I want to perform an ajax call, but jQuery navigates to controller method insted of asynchronous request.
In a view, I have this code:

```
<a href="#" class="btn btn-info" style="margin-left: 15px" id="clearLogs"><?=Yii::t('app', 'Clear log history')?></a>
```

In a custom js file I have this (after document ready):

```
$('#clearLogs').click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();  // don't follow the link
        $.ajax({
            url: '/admin/clear',
            data: {id: 1},
            success: function(){
                alert('success');
            }
        });
    });
```

And in controller method I have this:

```
public function clear() {
        if (Yii::$app->request->isAjax) {
            $flag = 777;
            // .....
            Yii::$app->response->format = Response::FORMAT_JSON;
            return ['flag' => $flag];
        }
    }
```

**How do i perform this ajax call without page reload?**

Answer (score 0):

A link is used to navigate to next page, it is not recommend to use a link to perform button type function. anyway you can use yii2 component to built a link, which has option to not to re-direct

```
<?php echo Html::a(Yii::t('app', 'Clear log history'))',$url=false,['class'=>'btn btn-warning','id'=>'clearLogs']); ?>
```

Comment: No, this did not help

Answer (score 0):

Change `clear()` to `actionClear()`.

[Yii2 URL Routing](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-runtime-routing.html)

Comment: Yeah, changed, still no result!